# How do I force a refresh after rendering animation?

Tags: rendering, animation

This has probably been asked and answered elsewhere, but I can't find it, so....

I designed a simple animated logo in Blender, with a spinning earth between two light-emitting text objects, with two point lamps for extra light. I rendered and saved the animation, and then used a gif conversion utility to save it as a gif. That all worked fine, but ...

... I decided I wasn't satisfied with the lighting. So I did Save As to start a new file, deleted the two point lamps from my original file, then added two Sun lamps (a Sun emitting a golden color from the left, a Moon emitting a pale blue from the right) and two dim Hemi lamps for high- and low-fill.

But when I Render I still get my original lighting. Similarly, if I Render Animation, I still get the original lighting.

How do I refresh the render process so I can see my new lighting?

Here is the Blender file:

[image]

UPDATE: Simply, it's not performing new renders. I deleted all of the original render frames, then clicked Render ... and I get a blank screen, because render image it had been displaying is no longer there.

UPDATE2: I went back and reopened the original file, from which I did a Save-As to create this new file ... and the original will not perform a new render either.

If I click the Render button, I get a blank screen, because the previous render (that it had been displaying) has been deleted.

Again, this ***is not*** about what I see in my 3D View. I see my lighting changes there. But I can't render a new image, or a new animation, at all.

UPDATE3: The solution was, per the answer below, to turn off *Sequencing* and *Compositing* in *Properties > Render > Post Processing*.

The relighted animation starts with this frame:

[image: Frame 1]

In the 180th frame, the earth has almost completed one rotation:

[image: Frame 180]

The lighting looks as I'd hoped: warm sunlight from direct left and cool moonlight from direct right, with dim neutral lights along the centerline to mute what would otherwise be a deep shadow at the sunset-moonrise horizon.

In clock terms, it's 12:00 noon on the left rim of the earth, and 12:00 midnight on the right rim. In terms of physics, my moonlight is far too bright; it's 1/2 the intensity of the sunlight, whereas in reality the ratio is about 1:400,000. But with the cooler color, it gives the effect I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh anything, lighting is always up to date and recalculated per render, unless you somehow baked it into the objects.

<s>How are you rendering this, using Cycles? Could you post some screenshots or perhaps a blender file?</s>

*Hemi* lights are not supported in Cycles, they will render as point lights as stated in the [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/lamps.html), and in most situations you will want only one sun light in your scene, so perhaps use some area lights instead, and use the world background for ambient light.

**Edit**

You scene is updating real time as expected, see bellow.

[image: Lighting update]

Deleting lights updates the scene immediately

**Some random tips**

*Hemi* lights are like [ambient lights](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/lighting/lamps/hemi.html), they emit light from a 180º dome, you generally do not want many of them in your scene. Many will cause a washed out and bland lighting that will absorb details.

Also sun lights are generally used sparingly in most scenes because they emit parallel rays of light. Try using a mix of spot lights, point lights and area lamps instead.

**Edit II**
Disable *Compositing* and *Sequencer* in the *Properties Window > Render > Post Processing*

Comment: I added the Blender file above. I don't remember baking anything. But I even tried restarting my computer, and it still renders with the original lighting. None of the new lights has any effect. It's as if that image is cached somehow.

Comment: Updated answer above

Comment: Yes, it updates in the 3D View. But I can't render it. Clicking the Render button simply tries to reload a previous rendered image (that I've since deleted.) See my update above. As for trying a different lighting mix, I can't see what my current mix produces, let alone know whether I want to change it ... because I can't render a new image.

Comment: Disable Compositing and Sequencer in the rendering panel, answer above updated